# WPF: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException when trying to bind to static property

Tags: c#, wpf

What would be the problem here? I has to do with the xaml code.
I'm trying to update a static property from different classes and update a textbox.
The crazy thing is that this example works fine:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/binding-static-properties-in-wpf-4-5/

Thanks in advance.

I get this message:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
InnerException  {"Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type."}   System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
```

My xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtbx" Text="{Binding Path=(local:Class3.Count), 
Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Grid.Row="1" Width="40" 
Height="20" ></TextBox>
```

My Code:

```
class Class3
{
    private static string count;
    public static string Count
    {
        get
        { return count; }
        set
        {
            if (value != count)
            {
                count = value;
                OnStaticPropertyChanged(); 
            }
        }
    }

    public static event EventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;
    static void OnStaticPropertyChanged() 
    {
        var handler = StaticPropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`EventHandler` is the wrong delegate type for the `StaticPropertyChanged` event.

Similar to the INotifyPropertyChanged interface's PropertyChanged event, it must be `PropertyChangedEventHandler`:

```
class Class3
{
    private static string count;
    public static string Count
    {
        get { return count; }
        set
        {
            if (value != count)
            {
                count = value;
                OnStaticPropertyChanged(nameof(Count));
            }
        }
    }

    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

    private static void OnStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```